# How to open SVG using QT c++

Tags: c++, qt, svg

I'm trying to create and save `QGraphicsScene` to `.svg` file and my code works properly. Which creates rectangle,circle and save it into `.svg`  But problem is which can only open rectangles only,how can I implement this to open circle(ellipse too) Please help me.

here are my codes.

**readsvg.h**

```
#ifndef READSVG_H
#define READSVG_H
#include <QList>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>

class ReadSVG
{
public:
    ReadSVG();
    static QList<QGraphicsRectItem *> getElements(const QString filename);
    static QRectF getSizes(const QString filename);

    //static QList<QGraphicsEllipseItem *> getElements(const QString filename);
    //static QRectF getSizes(const QString filename);

};

#endif // READSVG_H
```

**readsvg.cpp**

```
#include "readsvg.h"
#include <QPen>
#include <QFile>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDomDocument>
#include <QStringList>

ReadSVG::ReadSVG()
{

}

QList<QGraphicsRectItem *> ReadSVG::getElements(const QString filename)
{
    QList<QGraphicsRectItem *> rectList;    // We declare in the stack a list of rectangles

    QDomDocument doc;       // document object
    QFile file(filename);   // Open our SVG file
    // If it did not open or could not transfer content to QDocDocument
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) || !doc.setContent(&file))
        return rectList;    // then return the list, but empty

    // Look in the document for all objects with the tag g
    QDomNodeList gList = doc.elementsByTagName("g");
    // We start to sort them out
    for (int i = 0; i < gList.size(); i++) {
        QDomNode gNode = gList.item(i);     // Select the node from the list
        QDomElement rectangle = gNode.firstChildElement("rect");    // And we search in it for an element with the tag rect

        // If the resulting elements are not zero, then
        if (rectangle.isNull()){
            continue;
        } else {
            // begin to form a rectangle
            QGraphicsRectItem *rect = new QGraphicsRectItem();
            // This flag makes the object moveable, it will be required for verification
            rect->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
            // We take sizes from the rect tag
            QDomElement gElement = gNode.toElement();
            rect->setRect(rectangle.attribute("x").toInt(),
                          rectangle.attribute("y").toInt(),
                          rectangle.attribute("width").toInt(),
                          rectangle.attribute("height").toInt());

            /*
               We take the parameters of the colors gNode from the node element
               yes yes yes ... it's from gNode, not from rectangle. These parameters are stored in the tag g
             * */
            QColor fillColor(gElement.attribute("fill", "#ffffff"));    // fill color
            fillColor.setAlphaF(gElement.attribute("fill-opacity","0").toFloat());
            rect->setBrush(QBrush(fillColor));

            // as well as the color and thickness of the outline
            QColor strokeColor(gElement.attribute("stroke", "#000000"));
            strokeColor.setAlphaF(gElement.attribute("stroke-opacity").toFloat());

            rect->setPen(QPen(strokeColor,gElement.attribute("stroke-width", "0").toInt()));
            rectList.append(rect);  // add a rectangle to the list
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return rectList;
}

QRectF ReadSVG::getSizes(const QString filename)
{
    QDomDocument doc;       // initialize the QDomDocument object on the stack
    QFile file(filename);   // Open our SVG file
    // If it did not open or could not transfer content to QDocDocument
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly) || !doc.setContent(&file))
        return QRectF(0,0,200,200); // then return the values ​​for the default scene

    /* Next, we take the list of elements with the tag svg.
     * In case the list of elements is not empty,
     * then we will take the dimensions of the graphic scene.
     * */
    QDomNodeList list = doc.elementsByTagName("svg");
    if(list.length() > 0) {
        QDomElement svgElement = list.item(0).toElement();
        QStringList parameters = svgElement.attribute("viewBox").split(" ");
        return QRectF(parameters.at(0).toInt(),
                      parameters.at(1).toInt(),
                      parameters.at(2).toInt(),
                      parameters.at(3).toInt());
    }
    return QRectF(0,0,200,200);
}
```

**widget.h**

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QSvgGenerator>

namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_btnSave_clicked();

    void on_btnOpen_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem *elipse;
    QGraphicsRectItem *rect;
    QString path;

};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

**widget.cpp**

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include "readsvg.h"

#include <QCursor>
#include <QFileDialog>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    QBrush redBrush(Qt::red);
    QBrush blueBrush(Qt::blue);
    QPen blackPen(Qt::black);
    blackPen.setWidth(6);

    elipse = scene->addEllipse(10,10,100,100,blackPen,redBrush);
    rect = scene->addRect(-10,-10,100,100,blackPen,blueBrush);
    rect->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);


}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString fileName= QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save image", QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath(), "BMP Files (*.bmp);;JPEG (*.JPEG);;PNG (*.png)" );
        if (!fileName.isNull())
        {
            QPixmap pixMap = this->ui->graphicsView->grab();
            pixMap.save(fileName);
        }
}

void Widget::on_btnSave_clicked()
{
    // Заберём путь к файлу и его имененем, который будем создавать
    QString newPath = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, trUtf8("Save SVG"),
        path, tr("SVG files (*.svg)"));

    if (newPath.isEmpty())
        return;

    path = newPath;

    QSvgGenerator generator;        
    generator.setFileName(path);    
    generator.setSize(QSize(scene->width(), scene->height()));  
    generator.setViewBox(QRect(0, 0, scene->width(), scene->height())); 
    generator.setTitle(trUtf8("SVG Example"));                          
    generator.setDescription(trUtf8("File created by SVG Example"));    


    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(&generator);  
    scene->render(&painter);   
    painter.end();              

}


void Widget::on_btnOpen_clicked()
{
    QString newPath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, trUtf8("Open SVG"),
                                                   path, tr("SVG files (*.svg)"));
    if (newPath.isEmpty())
        return;

    path = newPath;
    scene->clear();

    scene->setSceneRect(ReadSVG::getSizes(path)); // Set the size of the graphic scene

    // Install the objects on the graphical scene, get them using the getElements
    foreach (QGraphicsRectItem *item, ReadSVG::getElements(path)) {
        QGraphicsRectItem *rect = item;
        scene->addItem(rect);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can continue with the approach that you have started. Look for elements with the tag names that you want. Start with the "circle" tag. Here's what a ciricle tag might look like;

```
 <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="3" fill="#0f0"/>
```

Comment: I'm not clear your answer.can you please provide me full code to do this,because I'm new to QT.please help me